# 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in Laravel 10 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-10

Hi I am facing an issue to store record in categories table having its own id(Primary Key) as parent_id as foreign key (check the migration for details), when i save the data it shows following error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))
```

**My Migration Code is**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            //$table->integer('parent_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_keywords')->nullable();
            $table->integer('navbar_status')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('is_active')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            //$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
```

**My Controller Code to Store the Record is**

```
public function store(CategoryFormRequest $request){

        $data = $request->validated();

        $category = new Category();

        $slug = Str::of($data['name'])->slug('-');
        

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $category_image = date('ymd')."-".time()."c.".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('uploads/category/', $category_image);
        }

        if($request->hasFile('banner_image')){
            $bnr_file = $request->file('banner_image');
            $cat_banner_image = date('ymd')."-".time().'b.'.$bnr_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $bnr_file->move('uploads/category/',$cat_banner_image);
        }

        $category->parent_id        = $data['parent_id'];
        $category->name             = $data['name'];
        $category->slug             = $slug;
        $category->description      = $data['description'];

        $category->image            = $category_image;
        $category->banner_image     = $cat_banner_image;

        $category->meta_title       = $data['meta_title'];
        $category->meta_description = $data['meta_description'];
        $category->meta_keywords    = $data['meta_keywords'];
        $category->navbar_status    = $request->navbar_status == true ? 1 : 0;
        $category->is_active        = $request->is_active == true ? 1 : 0;
        $category->is_featured      = $request->is_featured == true ? 1 : 0;
        

        $category->created_by       = Auth::user()->id;

        $category->save();

        return redirect()->route('category-create')->with('success', 'Category Added Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: `default(0)` is wrong, you cant do that in this way. You can add it one line `$table->foreignId('parent_id')->constrained();`

Comment: @tf. Thankyou, you mean to say I have to replace following line from migration $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->default(0); with your given suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **migration** file use this instead of yours

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

           $table->foreignId('parent_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_keywords')->nullable();
            $table->integer('navbar_status')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);

            $table->foreignId('created_by')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

            $table->foreignId('updated_by')
                ->nullable()
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

when you are injecting a `FormRequest` class as dependency in Laravel, Laravel will validate the `request` **automatically** for you thus you dont need to validate it again in your controller. In your code use this: *Dont forget if `$request->all()` is not suitable then use `$request->only(['name', 'description', ...])`*. Try `dd($request->all())` and `dd($request->only(['name', 'description', ...])` to see the content to make sure every thing is fine.

```
public function store(CategoryFormRequest $request, Category $category){
        
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $category_image = date('ymd')."-".time()."c.".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('uploads/category/', $category_image);
        }

        if($request->hasFile('banner_image')){
            $bnr_file = $request->file('banner_image');
            $cat_banner_image = date('ymd')."-".time().'b.'.$bnr_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $bnr_file->move('uploads/category/',$cat_banner_image);
        }

        Category::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('category-create')->with('success', 'Category Added Successfully');
    }
```

next step is to create a listener for your model which called observer in artisan command `php artisan make:observer CategoryObserver`

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryObserver
{
    public function creating(Category $category)
    {
        $category->created_by = auth()->id();
        $category->slug = Str::of($category->name)->slug('-');
    }
    
    public function updating (Category $category)
    {
        $category->updated_by = auth()->id();
    }
}
```

and now you have to register your observer to your model, open `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` and add this line of code to the `boot` method like so:

```
namespace App\Providers;


use App\Models\Category;
use App\Observers\CategoryObserver;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;


class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
    ];

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Category::observe(CategoryObserver::class); // add this line of code
    }

    public function shouldDiscoverEvents(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable detailed answer, apricate your effort. let me try your given suggestions...